# General Method For Calculation of Enthalpy Change for a chemical reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry

**1. Enthalpy of reaction** defined as the enthalpy change observed in a constituent of a thermodynamic system when one mole of substance reacts completely.

**2. Enthalpy of formation** defined as the enthalpy change observed in a constituent of a thermodynamic system when one mole of a compound is formed from its elementary antecedents.

**3. Enthalpy of combustion** defined as the enthalpy change observed in a constituent of a thermodynamic system when one mole of a substance burns completely with oxygen.

**4. Enthalpy of hydrogenation** defined as the enthalpy change observed in a constituent of a thermodynamic system when one mole of an unsaturated compound reacts completely with an excess of hydrogen to form a saturated compound.

**5. Enthalpy of atomization** defined as the enthalpy change required to atomize one mole of compound completely.

**6. Enthalpy of neutralization** defined as the enthalpy change observed in a constituent of a thermodynamic system when one mole of water is formed when an acid and a base react.

**7. Standard Enthalpy of a solution** defined as the enthalpy change observed in a constituent of a thermodynamic system when one mole of a solute is dissolved completely in an excess of solvent so that the solution is at infinite dilution.

**8. Enthalpy of fusion** defined as the enthalpy change required to completely change the state of one mole of substance between solid and liquid states.

**9. Enthalpy of vaporization** defined as the enthalpy change required to completely change the state of one mole of substance between liquid and gaseous states.

**10. Enthalpy of sublimation** defined as the enthalpy change required to completely change the state of one mole of substance between solid and gaseous states.

**11. Lattice enthalpy** defined as the energy required to separate one mole of an ionic compound into separated gaseous ions to an infinite distance apart (meaning no force of attraction).

**12. Enthalpy of mixing** defined as the enthalpy change upon mixing of two (non-reacting) chemical substances.

These definitons were taken from [the wikipedia article for enthalpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy#Enthalpy_changes).

Each enthalpy seems to come with its own formula.
Is there a general approach for solving enthalpy change-related questions for reactions instead of having to memorize a formula for each and every case?

If there is an obvious point that I'm missing kindly point it out.

Comment: Look up: born-haber cycle. you normally do not have to calculate all of these formulas.

Comment: You can use the algebraic form for the definition of enthalpy and derive the formula for each case yourself. Besides, about two thirds of the entropies can be found using tabulated data and a set of linear equations.

Comment: Now I understood, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @TanyaGupta Keep in mind you can answer your own question.